# How to save and get image from MongoDB with FastAPIMotor?

Tags: fastapi

I updated from Flask to FastAPI, my image saved in mongodb FS, how to save and get image from MongoDB with FastAPIMotor?

My Flask Code, photo is image:

```py
class TestFS(db.Document):
    uid = db.StringField()
    photo = db.FileField()
```

I can easily obtain, replace, and delete images corresponding to uids from the database, but how Motor do it?